# Is 'typeof' need to get the type information from the metadata or the information is store in the appDomain ?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

When i using the keyword 'typeof' ( on reference type ) is the JIT bring the information from the metadata or the information is store in the appDomain that the project is in ?

I rad in some place that when some application is start => the appDomain of the application ( appDomain that contain the application ) is load all the information about all the application types and then if there is some 'typeof' the information comes from the appDomain.

The other option is to bring the information from the MetaData and this is bad because we need to look for the right object type name ( ==> look for the right string ) and this can take time.

So .. From where the information is taken ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145930/how-does-typeof-work), it brings it from the metadata.
According to [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vancem/archive/2006/10/01/779503.aspx), it is really fast...