# Variable defined as parameter in function of type T undefined C#

Tags: c#, list, types, tostring

I have this static function here that decides the type of the passed parameter, and either calls the built in `ToString()` method on it if it's a generic, or calls a predefined custom facilitator to print out it's full contents if it can be enumerated over. Here's what I have so far;

```
public static String ToStringDecider<T> (T value)
{
    Type t = typeof(value);
    if (t.IsSubclassOf (Array) || t.IsSubclassOf (IList))
        return ToString_List (value);
    else if (t.IsSubclassOf (IEnumerable))
        return ToString_Enumerable (value);
    else if (t.IsSubclassOf (IDictionary))
        return ToString_Dictionary (value);
    else
        return value.ToString ();
}
```

However, the first reference to the variable `value` on line 3 comes up with a syntax error stating `"The name 'value' does not exist in the current context."` Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Comment: did you try `value.GetType()` ?

Comment: Why isn't `typeof()` sufficient?

Comment: Should'nt that be typeof(T) ?

Comment: Replacing that line with `Type t = T;` seems not to give any syntax errors. Would it accomplish the same thing?

Comment: it seems that you are influenced by `c` language somehow ;)

Comment: Moreso python. In fact, I hate C and C++ and would much rather use C#.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeof` does not take variable as argument, but rather type.

You want either:

```
Type t = typeof(T);
Type t = value.GetType();
```

Note that you also likely need explicit cast in calls to helper methods.

Comment: Wait; if `typeof(Array)` returns the _type_ of `Array`, then what type of object is `Array` itself? This is all very confusing.

Comment: @Maurdekye `typeof` is a keyword in C#, it's *not* a method being invoked, a'la `object.GetType()`. The compiler translates `typeof` into a specific MSIL opcode, and an invocation on `Type.GetTypeFromHandle` (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3145930/how-does-typeof-work for more detail).